# Measures of association between multiple binary time series

Tags: time-series, bernoulli-distribution, association-measure

I have two time series that are binary --

$$
Y_i(t_m) \text{ for } m = 1,..., \tau
$$
and
$$
Y_k(t_m) \text{ for } m = 1,..., \tau
$$

where either time series only take on the values 0 or 1. 
$$
Y_j(t_m) \in \{0, 1\} \text{ for } m=1,...,\tau
$$

I want to measure the association between these two times series, where the two time series are intrinsically non-linear and therefore estimators of cross-correlation are not the most appropriate statistics. I've seen some information on Mutual Information, but I'm unsure how to calculate a measure over the time course of a pair of time series.

Comment: What do you mean by "intrinsically non-linear"?

Comment: Ah -- I probably should have said something akin to the association being non-linear. I ended up using the cross-correlation function and it worked fine, but I was looking for a possibly more rigorous (or appropriate) measure of association.